# Jquery Validation not working for some textboxes

Tags: jquery, validation

Here is my form and jquery validation code. The problem is : it validates the first two fields i.e title and desc but it doesnt validate from breeds field.

```
<div class='span10 well' style='display:block;'>
  <h4>Listing Details : <span class='btn btn-info btn-    small' style='display:inline;'>Public</span><a href="#" class="tt"><img src='../../img/help.png' class='helpicon' /><span class="tooltip"><span class="top"></span><span class="middle">The information entered here will only shown to all customers who view your profile!</span><span class="bottom"></span></span></a></h4><br>
  <div class='test span9 well'>
    <form name='listingForm' id='listingForm' action='processListing.php' method='POST' onsubmit='validateForm()'>
            <label for "title"> Title: </label>
                    <input class='span8' type='text' name='title' id='title' placeholder='Catchy one-liner title...'>
                    <!-- help message -->
                    <a href="#" class="tt"><img src='../../img/help.png' class='helpicon' /><span class="tooltip"><span class="top"></span><span class="middle">A title is your first impression key! Make it catchy but informative to attract more customers.</span><span class="bottom"></span></span></a>
            <br><br><label for "desc"> Description: </label>
                    <textarea id="desc" name="desc" class='span8' rows=5 placeholder='Detailed description about your listing...'></textarea>
                    <a href="#" class="tt"><img src='../../img/help.png' class='helpicon' /><span class="tooltip"><span class="top"></span><span class="middle">A detailed description about your listing helps prospective customers know more about you. Talk about your pet, your family, how much you love your pet or an overview about how you can take the best possible care of the customer's four-feeted friend!</span><span class="bottom"></span></span></a>
  </div>
  <div class='myspan well'>
     <label for "breeds"> Breeds: <a href="#" class="tt"><img src='../../img/help.png' class='helpicon' /><span class="tooltip"><span class="top"></span><span class="middle">Key in all the breeds that you are willing to host. The more the merrier, so select as many as you want!</span><span class="bottom"></span></span></a></label>
             <input  type='text' name='breeds' id='breeds' value='' placeholder='Breeds you are willing to take in' onfocus='getDynamicData("Breed",this)'>

     <br><br><label for "boardingtype"> Accomodation Type: 
     <a href="#" class="tt"><img src='../../img/help.png' class='helpicon' /><span class="tooltip"><span class="top"></span><span class="middle">The type of accomodation that you can provide for the customer's best friend!</span><span class="bottom"></span></span></a>
     </label>

             <input type='radio' name='boardingtype' id='Apartment'> Apartment
             <input type='radio' name='boardingtype' id='House'> House
             <input type='radio' name='boardingtype' id='Boarding'> Boarding
     <br><br>
     <label for "amenities"> Amenities: 
     <a href="#" class="tt"><img src='../../img/help.png' class='helpicon' /><span class="tooltip"><span class="top"></span><span class="middle">Amenities available for a customer's pet. Choose all that apply. If you have more, be sure to mention it in the description of your listing.</span><span class="bottom"></span></span></a>
     </label>
             <input type='checkbox' id='amenity1' name="amenity1" value='Y'> <span style='padding-left: 10px'>Proximity to Vet</span>
             <br><input type='checkbox' id='amenity2' name="amenity2" value='Y'> <span style='padding-left: 10px'>Play Area</span>
             <br><input type='checkbox' id='amenity3' name="amenity3" value='Y'> <span style='padding-left: 10px'>24x7 Caretaker</span>
             <br><input type='checkbox' id='amenity4' name="amenity4" value='Y'> <span style='padding-left: 10px'>Toys</span>
  </div>
```

here is my jquery validation:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#listingForm").validate({
            rules: {
                title: "required",
                desc: "required",
                breeds: "required",
                price: {
                    required: true,
                    },

            },
            messages: {
                title: "blah blah",
                desc: "blah blah",
                breeds: "blah blah",

                price:"blah blah"
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: You've got a syntax error in your validation rules. Remove the comma at the end of "price: { required: true, },"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the remaining fields are not part of the form.  Forms and divs have to be nested properly. You have:

```
<div class='test span9 well'>
```

before the beginning of the form. The `</div>` that matches this also implicitly ends the form. If you want to split the form into multiple divisions, you need to move the `<div>` tags inside the `<form>`.

You're also missing the closing `</form>` and `</div>` for the `span9` division.